# ADT/Eclipse: New Android Application window: default value for Minimum Required SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Let's say if I permanently decided to do all my android projects with minimum required SDK - API 18 (or for that matter, decide to use API 5 as the minimum throughout); How can I configure ADT/Eclipse so that the 'New Android Application' window automatically preselects my choice of Minimum Required SDK?

- Does ADT/Eclipse has a configuration file for this that I can change?
- If not, Is the default value hardcoded in the particular version of ADT/Eclipse ?